# XCTest:verify view with tag is presented

Tags: ios, xctest, xctestcase, viewwithtag, xcode9.4

I'm adding a view with a tag in `viewDidAppear` but I implementing an unit test to verify the view is present in the superview but is returning nil.

Here is my testCase:

```
func testVerifiedViewWithTagIsLoadIt() {
    let sut = ViewController()
    _ = sut.view
    let view = sut.view.viewWithTag(10)
    XCTAssertNotNil(view)
    XCTAssertNotNil(sut.view.viewWithTag(10))
}
```

[image]

My question is how can I verify the view with tag is load it from XCTest?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `viewDidAppear` won't get called on `sut` in your test. Asking for the ViewControllers `view` will only trigger `viewDidLoad`. So you probably want to add the tagged View in `viewDidLoad`!

If you do that your test will pass.